# Figuring out notation of random variables

Tags: probability

[image]

Hi, I'm currently working on probability and statistics question and have become a little stuck on understanding this question.

Could someone explain to me what an N(3,4) variable is as I haven't come across it in my notes at all.

Thanks!

Comment: can you proceed by yourself or do you need further help?

Comment: I think I may need further help sorry. I have nothing in my notes about Gaussian random variables  or Z-tables but I have had suggestions from peers that it may be a normal distribution but I don't know if thats correct.

Comment: So, I have found the Z-score formula $Z=\frac{x-\mu}{\alpha}$ but I'm not sure what the value of X is supposed to be. and how do you work out how to change it from X to Y ?

Comment: answer edited with full details. Hope now it's clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone explain to me what an N(3,4) variable is ?

It is a [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) random variable with mean 3 and variance 4

Assuming independence between $X$ and $Y$, using properties of

1. Gaussian distribution
2. linearity of expectation
3. quadratics property of variance,

You get that

$$Y\sim N(11;100)$$

Then you can solve the request by standardizing and using Z-table

---

Further explanation:

1. Expectation is a linear operator thus

$$E(5X-4)=5\times 3-4=11$$

2. Variance is a quadratic operator thus

$$V(5X-4)=5^2\times 4=100$$

3. Linear combination of gaussian is still gaussian thus

$$P(Y>18.5)=P(Z>\frac{18.5-11}{\sqrt{100}})=1-\Phi(0.75)=1-0.7734=0.2266$$

$$\Phi(0.75)=\int_{-\infty}^{0.75} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt=0.7734$$

is tabulated in Z-table. If you are not familiar with Z-table you cannot solve the problem.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I really appreciate  it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $Y = 5X - 4,$ then $Y > 18.5$ if and only if
$5X - 4 > 18.5$, which in turn is true if and only if $X > \frac{18.5 + 4}{5} = 4.5.$

So really you are just being asked to find the value of $P(X > 4.5).$
You don't actually need to figure out the distribution of $Y,$
although for other purposes it is good to know how to do that.